# How to export the .NET project having connected with database?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have completed my .net project using visual studio 2012. How can I export my project so that I can run it on other pc too. The problem is that the database is not working on others pc bt perfectly working on my lappy. Why is it so and how can I solve this problem?? Please anybody help me out....

Comment: Is it an ASP or Winforms app? What database are you using?

Comment: Its winform and database is MySQL

Comment: Should every other PC/installation have its own database or should all connect to one central database?

Comment: First, you shoyld say deploy not export. Do you have the .Net framework installed on the target PC? If the database is located in another machine, you need to modify the connection string accordingly. Can you show us how you connect to the db server.

Comment: can you tell us how you set connectionString ?

Answer (score 0):

Get this situation at work fairly regularly as we have multiple instances of SQL Server and MySQL (Not so many of these) and deploying then testing the program can be quite laborious and any change in the deployment means you have to go back to the original, change and re-deploy.

What I would do is install visual studio express, or visual studio 2012 shell on the local machine where the deployment is going to take place and debug there.  If it is a corporate environment where licensing is an issue, installing visual studio express will mean that you do NOT have to purchase a license and therefore not incur cost.

The other situation is that you connect from your local machine to the MySql database but you'll have to open firewall ports which could get messy and, testing the program will not give you accurate performance results as your accessing a database over a network thats not configured for it.

There are other options such as using an attached database but again, gets messy with you changing the structure of your program.

My advice is go with the visual studio express solution...

Comment: I would totally prefer remote debugging instead of installing a complete VS if I just want to debug an deployed application within my network.

Comment: Totally understand your approach on this and your decision.  In this instance now I would (If I were you) start looking at a centralised solution for running the database on.  This would solve the problem of multiple users and resources and any future development or deployment.  MySql is also very scalable and requires minimal resources so cost is minimal in this situation so, consider this approach.  If this is not an option, then you'll have to look at opening up the firewall ports for MySql, user login creation, then amending/ creating your query string.